# How to execute a 7zip sfx with extra command line parameters

Tags: command-line, windows-installer, 7zip, sfx

I have an installer (installer.msi) and I made a self-extracting 7zip with a config file.
Here's my config file :

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
ExecuteFile="Installer.msi"
ExecuteParameters="TARGETDIR=\"[DirectoryPath]\" ALLUSERS=1"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

**These ExecuteParameters need to be embedded.**

Now I have 2 scenario, I want to be able to execute it like normal or fully silent. To execute it fully silent I want to use the /qn switch when executing it from the command line :

```
.\installer.exe /qn
```

The problem is if ExecuteParameters is set in the config file, those extra parameters are ignored but works as expected when ExecuteParameters is not set (Tested it).

How can I give these extra parameters to the .msi without embedding it in the config file?